# Name a Cell Range After Checking it Doesn't Have a Range Name

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I'm trying to cycle through a selection of cells and rename those cells based on text values on the spreadsheet.

```vb
Sub naming()

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim to_offset As Integer

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    Answer = InputBox("Column Where Named Are?")
    col_number = Range(Answer & 1).Column

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        cel.Name.Delete
        to_offset = col_number - cel.Column
        cel.Name = cel.Offset(0, to_offset).Value
    Next cel

End Sub
```

The delete command is the problem - so I thought I'd check for names using Len() but get a 1004 error.

If there are no names already defined for the cell it works (but I can't leave the delete code in).
If there are names already defined for the cell it works (and I use the delete).

I need to use the delete for existing names - but have it step over blank names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be to wrap the line in question between  `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0`, so the code would look like that

```
    On Error Resume Next   'skip line in case of an error
    cel.Name.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0        'reset error handling
```

Using `On Error Resume Next` tells VBA to ignore the error and continue on. There are specific occasions when this is useful. Most of the time you should avoid using it. I think this might be a case where you could use it.

Or you wrap the code in a sub

```
Sub deleteName(rg As Range)

    On Error GoTo EH
    rg.Name.Delete
    
    Exit Sub

EH:
    
End Sub
```

and use it like that

```
For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        deleteName cel
        to_offset = col_number - cel.Column
        cel.Name = cel.Offset(0, to_offset).Value
Next cel
```

But in this case this is IMHO not much of a difference.

Further reading on [Error handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/)

Comment: Nice explanation of the `On Error Resume Next` caveats +:) - Fyi You might be interested in my answer demonstrating the rather unknown possibilities of **`Range.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)`**, aka as `Range.Value(11)`!

Answer (score 0):

**A quick and direct way to delete names in selection**

In addition to @Storax 'es solution you might benefit from the fact that the relatively unknown function [`rng.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) (analyzing the entire sheet structure) returns also *all existing* names of a selected range as XML string. This saves further error handling.

Assign them to an array and delete them in a loop as follows:

```
Option Explicit                           ' code module header

Sub DelNamesInSelectedRange()
'a) Define selected range by any method
    Dim selectedRng As Range
    Set selectedRng = Application.Selection
'b) Get all names in selected range via XMLSpreadsheet analyze
    Dim myNames
    myNames = GetNames(selectedRng)
'c) Delete received names
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(myNames) - 2
        ThisWorkbook.Names(myNames(i)).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

**Help function `GetNames()`**

Applying some **XML** logic including namespaces via *XPath search string** allows to extract all names of the specified range and to return an array of all existing names.

*A sample extract of this xml might be:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
' <!-- ... omitting styles etc -->
' <!-- ... -->
' <Names>
'  <NamedRange ss:Name="FirstName" ss:RefersTo="=Sheet1!R1C1"/>
'  <NamedRange ss:Name="SecondName" ss:RefersTo="=Sheet1!R3C1"/>
'  <NamedRange ss:Name="LastName" ss:RefersTo="=Sheet1!R2C3"/>
' </Names>
' <!-- ... -->
'</Workbook>
```

```
Function GetNames(rng As Range)
'[0]Get Value(11)
    Dim s As String
    s = rng.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)   ' or: rng.Value(11)
'[1]Set xml document to memory
    Dim xDoc As Object: Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
'[2]Add namespaces
    xDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
    "xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' " & _
    "xmlns:ht='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'"
'[3]Get cells with Names/NamedRange/@Name
    If xDoc.LoadXML(s) Then            ' load wellformed string content
        Dim cell As Object, cells As Object
        'Set cells = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ss:Cell[ss:Data/@ss:Type='Number']") ' XPath using namespace prefixes
        Set cells = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ss:Names/ss:NamedRange/@ss:Name") ' XPath using namespace prefixes
        Dim tmp(): ReDim tmp(1 To cells.Length)
        For Each cell In cells
            Dim i As Long: i = i + 1
            tmp(i) = cell.Text
        Next cell
        '[4]return "flat" array
        GetNames = tmp
    End If
End Function
```